# Python: Automatically change string to set in .intersection() method of Set?

Tags: python, set, intersection

I am new to Python (and have basic knowledge of Java) and learning it on my own at the moment by using the Head First Python, 2nd Edition book.

In one of the examples in the book, it shows how the .intersection() method of Sets is used. It does so in the following way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def search_for_vowels(word: str) -> set:
        """Return any vowels found in supplied word."""
        vowels = set('aeiou')
        return vowels.intersection(set(word))

    print(search_for_vowels('hitch-hiker'))
    print(search_for_vowels('sky'))
```

However, when I tried this on my own, I accidentally forgot the 'set' part in the above code (above the print statements), hence it became:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def search_for_vowels(word: str) -> set:
        """Return any vowels found in supplied word."""
        vowels = set('aeiou')
        return vowels.intersection(word)

    print(search_for_vowels('hitch-hiker'))
    print(search_for_vowels('sky'))
```

The code, however, did run without any problems and returned the correct output. This seems kind of strage to me, as I would be comparing a set to a string, and not a set to a set. My question therefore is: Does Python automatically convert a string to a set when performing the intersection() method of Set?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official docs, some `set` methods](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#set), including `intersection()`, accept an iterable for `other`:

> Note, the non-operator versions of [`union()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union), [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), [`difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), [`symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference), [`issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset), and [`issuperset()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) methods will **accept any iterable as an argument**. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')` .

and

> Note, the non-operator versions of the [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update), [`intersection_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection_update), [`difference_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference_update), and [`symmetric_difference_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference_update) methods **will accept any iterable as an argument**.

Emphasis mine. No conversion may be happening (I haven't checked the source code).

***Operator* vs *Non-operator*:**

From the docs:

> `union` (**others* )
> `set | other | ...`
> Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.

> `intersection` (**others* )
> `set & other & ...`
> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

So `|` is the operator for `union()`, and `&` is the operator for `intersection()`.

Examples:

```py
>>> # using the & operator, with a set
>>> set('abc') & set('cbs')
{'c', 'b'}
>>>
>>> # using the intersection method, with a set
>>> set('abc').intersection(set('cbs'))
{'c', 'b'}
>>>
>>> # using the & operator, with non-set (error)
>>> set('abc') & 'cbs'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'str'
>>>
>>> # using the intersection method, with non-set (okay)
>>> set('abc').intersection('cbs')
{'c', 'b'}
>>>
>>> # also applies to general operations, see link below
>>> # using the + operator with two integers
>>> 4 + 5
9
>>> # using the __add__ method
>>> (4).__add__(5)
9
```

See this [list of operators and their methods/functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions). Some built-in types, like sets and dictionaries, each have their own operator mapping as well. And using the `__dunder__` (double-underscore x2) magic methods, these can be implemented for user-defined objects as well.

Comment: Hey Aneroid, thanks for your reply and the official documentation. I was wondering if you would be able to explain the difference between non-operator and operator versions, as I have not heard of these terms before. Kindest regards, David

Answer (score 0):

The non-operator version accepts any iterable as an argument. By non-operator, I mean functional implementation of these operations like `.intersection()`, `.union()`, e.t.c.

If you want to use the operator version of this operation, all the variables should be set.

For Example -> `set1 & set2` requires both the operands of type set.

Comment: Hey Monark, thanks for your answer. This is the first time I have heard of (non) operator versions of .intersection(), etc. Would you be able to explain the difference between the two? Kindest regards, David

Comment: Is the difference perhaps that the non-operator version of, for instance, ```.intersection()``` is ```&```, and that it is more or less just a difference in notation? What is actually the operator version of ```.intersection()```?

Comment: @David Yes, that's correct. See my [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531353/1431750) above for examples.

Answer (score -1):

The [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method requires an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#:%7E:text=has%20finished%20executing.-,iterable,method%20or%20with%20a%20__getitem__()%20method%20that%20implements%20Sequence%20semantics.,-Iterables%20can%20be) as a parameter.

You are passing a `string`(word) which is an iterable, hence it works successfully.

Comment: Hey Syed, many thanks for your reply and help!

Comment: Please don't link to unofficial and unverified sources when the official docs will do just fine.